# Defining CharSet for static HTML files

Tags: google-app-engine, http-headers, content-type, static-files, app.yaml

I just tried several times to define character set for static files served from Google App Engine and failed miserably.

File does contain correct meta-equiv tag in header section of file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

But it's not being passed as header, browser needs to pick it up from the actual document.

Naturally if I use script (or Python Google App Engine program) then I can get it delivered correctly as response header.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I tried to add to app.yaml file rows:

```
- url: /
  static_files: root/create.html
  upload: root/create.html
  http_headers:
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

But appcfg.py just tells me:
Unexpected attribute 'http_headers' for object of type URLMap.
  in "9oxnet/app.yaml", line 41, column 5

Answer (score 8):

To fix this charset header issue for static files, you'll need to define charset in app.yaml file:

```
 - url: /
   static_files: root/create.html
   upload: root/create.html
   mime_type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Now Content-Type header for static files also correctly contains character set information.

```
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Some browser do not parse pages as quickly as possible, if charset information is not included in headers.